# Considering EFI and disk encryption is a /boot partition necessary anymore?

Tags: boot, partitioning, uefi, encryption

Considering EFI and disk encryption (with ubuntu 20.04) is a /boot partition necessary anymore?
In case of /boot necessity, is it relevant to crypt /boot partition ?

Comment: For the vast majority of users no, why it's not the default. But not everyone users default setups...

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case it is probably necessary:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Full_Disk_Encryption_Howto_2019#Detecting_UEFI_boot_mode

/boot encrypting is not essential.